# How to execute the shell script program file from the Java class

Tags: java, shell

I have written a shell script file which extracts the files, Please see below.

**File Name:**  unzip.sh

```
#/bin/sh
cd /home/zip;
UNZIPDIR=/home/unzip/;
for i in *.zip; do
    unzip "$i" -d "$UNZIPDIR"
    rm "$i";
done;
```

This shell script executes sucessfuly on putty,

```
 $> ./zip.sh
```

As i wanted to execute this script from my java class while i have tried several ways to invoke/execute the shell script file but it's not executing. Please see below java code.

```
//First try
            File executorDirectory = new File("/home/zip");
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("./unzip.sh");
            processBuilder.directory(executorDirectory);
            Process p = processBuilder.start();  
            p.waitFor() 

            //Second try
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/zip/unzip.sh");
```

Comment: You use Java 7+ , right? If yes why not just use the FileSystem API instead of relying on an external script?

Comment: read stdStream & ErrorStream from the process.

Comment: Any exception thrown ?

Comment: @fge yes it can be done using file api but processing time is bit fast when dealing with big chunk of data.

Comment: @sam_eera no, not any exception...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you fail to account for the process' standard output/error (as mentioned by @Yazan in the comments). You need to `.get{Output,Error}Stream()` from the created process and read from them (even if it is only to discard it).

The real problem however is that you use an external shell script for something which is entirely doable in Java itself. See [this page](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.fr/2011/08/java-7-working-with-zip-files.html) which gives an example of how to extract a zip file entirely with Java code; to delete a file, use [`Files.delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete-java.nio.file.Path-).